# android select time interval using a timeline control

Tags: java, android-spinner, android, android-timepicker

I need a control that forces the user to select a date and time within specific intervals.

I see that datapickerDialog has setMin and setMax, but it's not enough.

The best way is to have a selectable timeline with 5 minutes resolution, with min and max date, and with possibility to hide a certain interval between min and max.

I was hoping to find a custom control in the network, but have not found anything